# My app goes straight into the MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app just like WhatsApp but I have a problem. The app is suppose to go into the LoginActivity but instead it goes straight into the MainActivity without me logging in.

I tried changing the launcher scene in android manifest and the same thing is happening. I tried adding `mAuth.signOut();` at the end of both of my  `loadingBar.dismiss();`. I tried changing this 
`SendUserToMainActivity();` to this `SendUserToRegisterActivity();`. I deleted all of the accounts in the firebase database also.

LoginActivity:

```
private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private Button LoginButton, PhoneLoginButton;
private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword;
private TextView NeedNewAccountLink, ForgetPasswordLink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    InitializeFields();

    NeedNewAccountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SendUserToRegisterActivity();

        }
    });


    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AllowUserToLogin();

        }
    });


}

private void AllowUserToLogin() {

    String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{

        loadingBar.setTitle("Logging In");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }

                            else{

                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                            }
                    }
                });

    }

}

private void InitializeFields() {

    LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    PhoneLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.phone_login_button);
    UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
    ForgetPasswordLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forget_password_link);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (currentUser != null){

        SendUserToMainActivity();

    }
}

private void SendUserToMainActivity() {

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }

private void SendUserToRegisterActivity() {

    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(registerIntent);
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you show your manifest?

Comment: OnStart fun check current user.uid!= Null other wise you'll always get the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the cache of your app once, change launcher from Main Activity to Login Activity Rebuild the app, and onStart of the LoginActivity  you're getting the user logged in that's why he's always sending you to mainActivity,
 **It doesn't matter if you have removed all users in firebase you'll get auth until you'll clear the cache.** 
Try this solution and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it worked. I think I had to clear the data on my emulator. Thanks a lot

Comment: Cool :)  I'm glad that it fixed the problem)

Comment: :) @HaykMkrtchyan he was receiving the user which is actually he deleted but caught up in the Auth that's why he can't stick to LoginActivity,

Comment: I understood. currentuser was not null :) That's why I told to do debug. He could recognize the problem very fast))

Comment: Yes, @Chaster App you have to check  current user.uid in onStart function.

Answer (score 1):

In `AllowUserToLogin()` you must place a

```
return;
```

statement after you show the `Toast` with the error message.
Also remove the `else` after checking the password:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
loadingBar.setTitle("Logging In");
..................................
```

**Edit**
After you posted the manifest, I see that your `LAUNCHER` activity is `MainActivity` although you mention in your question that:

> I tried changing the launcher scene in android manifest and the same
>   thing is happening.

You must also change the `LAUNCHER` activity to `LoginActivity`

Comment: I just tried all of that and it didn't work. I just updated my manifest to what it currently looks like

Comment: *it currently looks like* this is wrong. Set `LoginActivity` as the LAUNCHER activity. Swap `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Change your manifest like this.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
<activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

When opens login activity, check if user already logged send him into MainAcitivty.

Also that will be good if you will have a method, where you will check text fields verification.
Something like this:

```
public boolean verified() {
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
  }

  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
      Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return false;
  }

 return true;
}
```

And do like this:

```
if(verified){
    loadingBar.setTitle("Logging In");
    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    loadingBar.show();
    //And so on.
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. The same thing is happening

Comment: So you open app and it opens MainActivity?

Comment: Yes as soon as I run the app I go to the MainActivity

Comment: Can you debug your app and see what's happening and why happening?

Comment: I don't know man)) There's something wrong. You can try to delete MainAcitivty, remove functionality related to MainActivity and try to open the app :) If that will work, you can create your MainAcitivty again. And show the code in MainActivity if you can:)

Comment: Yes and this line `currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` Is that works good and what it does? Yes and I think something goes wrong in onStart() method you wrote.